# Remove the whole history of a specific branch from git repository

Tags: git

I would like to remove a branch from my repository and also from the history so the .git folder will get smaller.
The branch was never merged to master.

I already tried to remove the branch with

`git branch -D <branch name>` and then to run

```
 git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

I also tried

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
```

but nothing worked. the folder .git size didn't change at all and the commit didn't disappear, I could still see them with:

```
 git show <commit hash>
```

- everything i tried was in local repository.

Is there any way to do this? if so, can you write the exact way to do it?

Its also possible i did something wrong with those commands. so please write it detailed.

Thank you.

Comment: So the branch is deleted, but the commits are still visible with `git fsck` ?

Comment: no, when i run git fsck it doesn't show anything but i still able to use git show on those commits.

Comment: what does `git branch -a` say? Does the branch disappear from the listing after you've deleted it with `git branch -D <branch_name>`?

Comment: Do these commits belong solely to this particular branch?

Comment: the branch disappeared from git branch -a output.

Comment: so you want to remove all commits?

Comment: yes they are solely.

Comment: yes, i want to remove all the commits under this branch

Comment: If you deleted the branch and git fsck shows no dangling objects, but you can still show a commit from that branch, than there is only the possibility left, that that branch/commit was merged. Everything else seems impossible to me

Comment: you can see while running gitk that the branch never wasn't merged.

Comment: Try that with your commit `git branch --contains <commit>`. The commit has to be somewhere.

Comment: i tried it, nothing contains it.

Answer (score -1):

Radical way:

Try to clone only master branch to new repository.
Fetch some necessary branches from old repository.
Delete old repository, rename new to old.